# Django aggregation over filtered query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Assuming I have these two models :

```
class User(models.model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Item(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey( User )
    enabled = models.BooleanField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to create an optimal query and get : Top 10 users which have at least 10 **enabled**
items and the highest average price of that total items (sorted by best avarage)

In other words I am trying to create a top 10 "leaderboard" on my site for the users that own an average best priced items, however some of the items may be disabled and still exist on my database, I am trying to get rid of them on my ORM query but cant find a good way of doing it.

This operation is run every 5 minutes or so, it is not running while generating a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test right now, but I think this should work:

```
topusers = User.objects.prefetch_related(
                'item_set'
            ).filter(
                item_set__enabled=True
            ).annotate(
                item_count=models.Count('item_set'),
                avg_price=models.Avg('item_set__price')
            ).filter(
                item_count__gte=10
            ).order_by('-avg_price').all()
```

Comment: Put the `item_set__enabled` (double underscore) before the annotation and it will get the count and average price of just the enabled items. Otherwise, this should produce the desired results.

Comment: @knbk Yeah fixed the double underscore AND moved the enabled before, because it makes more sense to count on enabled items.